# Modify page based on user's products

Tags: ruby-on-rails

One User has many products, one product only belongs to one user. In User profile, I want to implement this concept:

1. If user does not have a product, "Create new product" button is available
2. If user already has a store, both "Create new product" and list of products that can be clicked on to direct to the product itself

```rb
<% if @product.include? current_user.id %>
<%= link_to 'My product', product_path %>
<% end %>
<%= link_to 'Create New Product', new_product_path %>
<%= link_to 'Edit', edit_user_registration_path %>
```

Comment: Please read [Rails Assosiation](https://www.sitepoint.com/brush-up-your-knowledge-of-rails-associations/) for better knowledge and understanding.

Comment: What is your question?

Answer (score -1):

If you implement the correct relationship the following code will work

```js
<%current_user.products.present?%>
  <%@current_user.products.map|product|%>
<%= @product.name%>
<button> Create Product </button>
 <%end%>
<%else%>
<button> Create Product </button>
<%end%>
```

Rails Association(https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html)